# Dropzone debug and ajax messages from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dropzone.js

I'm using latest Dropzone.js release 3.7.1 and PHP script to upload file to server

I'm would like to get message back to drop zone area, on image
so i exit with

```
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
exit();
```

this display a generic dropzone error on image
but if i use

```
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
exit("My error");
```

I get "Invalid JSON response from server."

if i use

```
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
header('Content-type: application/json');
exit(json_encode(array('message' => '$msg', code => 500)));
```

i get "[object Object]"

Does drop zone pass file upload as an array or as a single file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the response Content-Type to `text/plain` and just send the message, or set the Content-Type to `application/json` and send `{"error": "message"}`.

In both cases you need to send an error header, otherwise Dropzone will not interpret the response as an error:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
header('Content-type: text/plain');
exit("My error");
```